# How to bypass "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled" on a remote cloud virtual machine?

Tags: linux, docker, centos, virtualbox, docker-machine

I bought a cloud virtual machine and want to use docker-machine to create virtual machines on it

```
  docker-machine create --driver virtualbox vm1
```

but I get the following errors:

```
    Running pre-create checks...
    Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
```

since the machine I'm working on is a remote virtual machine, it is not possible for me to enable VT-X/AMD-v in the BIOS, how can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Can you get multiple, smaller, cloud VMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say exactly because you didn't state from which provider you've bought your VPS but usually virtual private servers do not have (and very often simply cannot) have virtualisation enabled (when they themselves are virtual already), so it probably is impossible to run additional virtual machines on it. If the machine is running linux though, regular docker containers (linux ones) should be able to run on it.

Comment: I want to create multiple virtual machines on one VPS to emulate multiple machines

Comment: It might be impossible in this case. Very often virtual machines offered by cloud providers do not provide additional virtualization layers. Because the machine you've bought is virtual itself it might not have the capacity to run virtual machines on itself thus splitting the allocated resources even further.